# Python Get minimum value without -inf

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find the minimum of an array without -inf values. What I could find there is numpy function to filter out NaNs but not -inf:

```
import numpy as np
np.nanmin([1, 2, np.nan, np.NINF])
```

The desired output is:

```
1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select the non -Infs and get the `min` ignoring `NaNs` with `np.nanmin` -

```
np.nanmin(a[a != -np.inf])
```

Sample run -

```
In [209]: a
Out[209]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan, -inf])

In [210]: np.nanmin(a[a != -np.inf])
Out[210]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `np.isfinite` to get only real values:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, np.NINF])
min_value = a[np.isfinite(a)].min()
# >>> 1.0
```

Comment: Nice, this works too! Just as a very very corner case if the array has only Infs and -Infs might cause trouble.

Comment: Might cause trouble for good reasons. Which value would you expect in this case?

Comment: Without -Infs and NaNs, we would be left with Infs, so I think we would expect Inf as the result in that case.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach using masked arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ma.masked_invalid([1, 2, np.nan, np.NINF]).min()
1.0
```

[masked_invalid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html) will ignore Inf and NaN values.